# else statement not executing with Object method Call

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

For some reason, I have an else if statement that does not want to run. The conditions (I think) have been met.

```
    int codeCheck = Integer.parseInt(itemCode);
    DataAccessImpl da = new DataAccessImpl();
    if(!rs.wasNull()) {
        while(rs.next()) {

            Products temp = new Products(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getDouble(3), rs.getBoolean(4));
            productsList.add(temp);
            request.setAttribute("productsList", productsList);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Scan.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    } 
    else if(da.codeExists(codeCheck) == false){
        Products wrongCode = null;
        productsList.add(wrongCode);
        System.out.println("THIS IS EXECUTING!");
        request.setAttribute("productsList", productsList);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Scan.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Here's the method in the DataAccessImpl Class

```
public boolean codeExists(int code) {
    final String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM productcatalogue WHERE code = ?";
        try {

            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(SELECT_QUERY); // Create query statement
            statement.setInt(1, code);

            ResultSet queryResult = statement.executeQuery();
            if (!queryResult.next()) { // Check if code entered exists
                return false;
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {

            sqlException.printStackTrace();

        }
        return true; //Otherwise the item exists
    }
```

Comment: You should provide a little more context. for example, the first block of code does not show what `rs` is and how it has been initialised. 
[Read this article on how to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, you failed telling us what you already tried and where exactly your code fails. Finally, I think you should also return false in the `catch` block.

Comment: Are you sure that queryResult has a value?

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure rs was surely null and the first if is not met then definitely it will go to your else if and will check if `(da.codeExists(codeCheck) == false)` and if this is also true then it will surely execute so you make sure that first if is false and else if is true other wise according to the design pattern it will not be executed.